# How to Set Default Dropdown value in magento1 custome form at admin side

Tags: module, adminhtml

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'attribute_magento',
        'select',
        array(
            'name'   => 'attribute_magento0',
            'container_id' => 'attribute-magento0',
            'values' => $values,
            'value' => 'vw',
    ));
```

i was try but it has not work 
any one have idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working code:

```
$fieldset->addField('attribute_magento', 'select',
    array(
        'name'   => 'attribute_magento0',
        'container_id' => 'attribute-magento0',
        'values' => $values,
        'value' => array('vw')
        )
);
```

This will work if you $values contains any options whose value is "vw".